# Why can we cast "servletRequest" to "HttpServletRequest"?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, filter, servlet-filters

In doFilter method, we use the code below to access to session :

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
```

But, "*HttpServletRequest*" extends "*servletRequest*", so theoretically we should not be able to put father in son.

Comment: except when you know that this `ServletRequest` is actually a `HttpServletRequest`

Comment: You can't extend an object (or a variable).. look at the *compile-time static type* of the expression (of "servletRequest") and you'll see that it does *not* extend HttpServletRequest. This is why Java needs the explicit cast: it could be [based on the static types] another non-HTTP ServletRequest.

Comment: Consider this: `Animal animal = NewDogOrCat(); Dog dog = (Dog)animal` - the cast to Dog is not guaranteed. Likewise, same for this: `ServletRequest servletRequest = NewHttpRequestOrNotHttpRequest(); HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)serveltRequest` (Just because it's "always" a HttpServletRequest does *not* affect the static type system or request type validation.)

Comment: sorry, your answer is not clear, could you please break it down for me?

Comment: The cast is required because Java only has static type information available during the compilation phase. See the linked question - "downcasting" is about *getting a more specific*-typed expression, as a HttpServletRequest (or a Dog) is *more specific* than a ServletRequest (or an Animal).